# Gmail can't decode multiline base64 encoded message

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, swiftmailer, base64url

I'm using `Swift_Message` to construct the message and `Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder` to encode the message,then in `Google_Service_Gmail_Message` I'm setting the encoded mesage with `->setRaw()` method.

I've been sending mail with this for quite some time and it used to work fine. Since yesterday it stopped working and the error message says

```
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'message.raw' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \"[base64 encoded message with CRLF after every 76th character]\"",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid value at 'message.raw' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \"[base64 encoded message with CRLF after every 76th character]\"",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
```

It works when I remove the CRLF. Any thoughts?

Ref: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.1.1

My code

```
    $msg = new Swift_Message();
    $msg->setCharset('UTF-8')
        ->addTo(/*recipient*/)
        ->setSubject(/*sbject*/)
        ->addPart(/*text content*/, "text/plain")
        ->addPart(/*html content*/, "text/html");
        
    $base64 = (new Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder)->encodeString($msg->toString());
    $base64_msg = rtrim(strtr($base64, '+/', '-_'), '=');

    $mailer  = $this->_getGmailService();// new Google_Service_Gmail(new Google_Client())
    $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $message->setRaw($base64_msg);
    $message->setThreadId($threadId);

    $mailer->users_messages->send('me', $message);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to try to replicate the issue?

Comment: This is pretty much how the code is written.

Answer (score 2):

I used `base64_encode($message->toString());` instead of

```
(new Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder)->encodeString($msg->toString());
```

Comment: That does solve the problem(which I'm using now) but doesn't follow RFC2822 standard.

Answer (score 0):

The library method you're using does a Base64 encoding and you need a [Base64URL](https://base64.guru/standards/base64url) encoded string as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages)

Comment: I've done that. `rtrim(strtr($data, '+/', '-_'), '=');`

Comment: You need to remove the line separators as well

Comment: But according to RFC2822 I shouldn't put more than 76 and must not more than 998 characters in one line!